# Can this problem be solved in polynomial time?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, computational-complexity, np-complete, discrete-optimization

I'd like to know about the complexity of the problem below. I believe it might not be possible to solve this with a polynomial time algorithm, but I'd be very happy to be proved wrong.

> **Problem:** Given a sequence of real numbers $a_{1},\dots,a_{n}$ and a collection of subsets $S_{1},\dots,S_{d}\subset\{1,\dots,n\}$, find a subset of the subsets $I\subset\{1,\dots,d\}$, such that their union $S=\cup_{i\in I}S_{i}$, satisfies
>
> $$ \sum_{j\in S}a_{j}>0 $$
>
> or prove that no such subset exists.

I'm interested in the worst-case complexity, in particular dealing with cases where the 'no such such subset exists' result is the answer. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Since the problem in clearly in NP, anyone who can conclusively answer "no, this _cannot_ be solved in polynomial time" will be famous.

Comment: If the answer is "yes", that answer can be certified by writing down explicitly an $I$ that works, and this certificate can clearly be checked in polynomial time (modulo however you propose to represent arbitrary reals in the first place). Thus by definition the problem is in NP.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that proving it is equivalent to some well studied NP-complete problem, or indeed finding that it already is one, would be the best way to go. Easier said than done tho!

Answer (score 1):

Even finding out *whether* such an $I$ exists is NP-complete.

Assuming a computationally reasonable representation of the "real" numbers $a_i$, it is easy to see that the problem is in NP: If the answer is "yes", that answer can be certified by writing down explicitly an $I$ that works, and this certificate can clearly be checked in polynomial time

For **NP-hardness**, we can reduce from the [Set Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) problem:

Given a family of $k$ subsets $A_i\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ we want to find out whether there are $p$ of the subsets whose union is all of $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$.

Define
$$ a_j = \begin{cases} 1 & 1 \le j \le m \\
-\frac1{p+1} & m+1 \le j \le m+k \\
-m+1 & j = m+k+1 \end{cases} $$
and
$$ S_i = A_i \cup\{m+i\}\cup\{m+k+1\} $$
This is an instance of your problem with $n=m+k+1$ and $d=k$, where an $I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,k\}$ has $\sum a_j>0$ exactly it it consists of at most $p$ of the $A_i$s that together cover $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks!

Comment: This result has helped me prove a theorem which is going in a paper that I am writing. I'd like to give you an acknowledgement for the helpful answer. How do you want me to call you there, is Dr Henning Makholm ok?

Comment: @Jasper: If it's all the same to you, I'd prefer you leave out the "Dr" prefix. It's not wrong as such, but I feel it makes me look like a self-important git.